# Django is not sending me an email when there is an error 500

Tags: django

After deploying my website, I would like to get an email with the errors when there is an error 500.

I am able to send normal emails with send_mail. I also have `DEBUG= False`, `ADMINS=[('name', 'email')]` and`SERVER_EMAIL = "domain email"`, however I and not getting any emails.

I believe it is because I created a custom template for handler500

**urls.py**

```
handler500 = myapp.error_500
```

**views.py**

```
def error_500(request):
    data = {}
    return render(request,'.../error_500.html', data)
```

How do I get an email with an error?

**Update**

After removing the custom handler500, I got the error email.
So my question in my custom method `error_500`, I know how to set up email, but how do I get the error report and include it in the body. What should i put in msg_plain

**views.py**

```
def error_500(request):
    if IN_PROD:
         sender='admin@myapp.com',
         to_email='admin@email.com',
         mail_subject='500 ERROR ALERT',
         msg_plain = DJANGO ERROR REPORT??? 

         send_mail(mail_subject, msg_plain,from_email=sender, recipient_list=[to_email])
    data = {}
    return render(request,'.../error_500.html', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the exact value of `ADMINS`? Based on your example, it's the wrong format. It should be:

```
ADMINS = [('name', 'name@email.com')]
```

And **not**:

```
ADMINS = [('name'), ('name@email.com')]
```

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, it is actually ADMINS = [('name', 'name@email.com')]